# Need a library for barcode scaning for windows mobile devices

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, barcode

I'm looking for an opensource library/SDK for windows mobile devices. My purpose is to scan a barcode from mobile's camera and retrieve its info. I used zxing for android but is not supported for windows mobile devices :(
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/qrcode.aspx

Comment: I've already checked that and it is only for QR barcodes!! I need a library for 1D barcodes like EAN, Code39 etc. 
Thnx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Several ideas spring to mind:

- If the device is network-connected, use .NET CF to capture images and send it to another device for processing (for example, through zxing)
- If the device must operate offline, you can bring Mysaifu JVM on the device and run zxing on it or barcode4j.
- Finally, zxing now includes some C# and C++ source -- you might be able to use that as a basis for a .NET CF port (after two years :)).

(If you want to include only .NET Compact solutions, you might want to edit your question to reflect that.)